# Firebase Transactions Reservations System

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a reservation system using firebase. The user can select a number of seats and i want to write them in my document. The selected seats are inside an array and they are objects,  like so:

```
    {
      reservationId: 'id', 
      selectedSeats: [{"x": 0, "y": 0,},
                      {"x": 1, "y": 0,},
                      {"x": 2, "y": 0,}]
    }
```

I want to ensure that no other user could write to the database with at least 1 same seat with transactions.

```
let transaction = db.runTransaction(t => {
  return t.get(venueId)
    .then(doc => {
      //I need to get all the objects inside the document and check their array of reservations.
      t.set(venueId, {reservation});
    });
}).then(result => {
  console.log('Transaction success!');
}).catch(err => {
  console.log('Transaction failure:', err);
});
```

How can i make the transaction fail if a seat is found in the array of each object inside the document?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `array-contains-any` for checking if there are any of your seats reserved on the db already and return a sucessful or failing promise depending on the results, also you need to create a reference to an empty document outside the transaction before you can create the document inside it, here is what it could look like:

```
//reference to a document that still does not exists
var docRef = db.collection(reservation).doc()
let transaction = db.runTransaction(t => {
  return t.get(venueId)
    .then(doc => {
      db.collection('reservation')
        .where('selectedSeats', 'array-contains-any', reservation.selectedSeats)
        .get()
        .then(snapshot =>{
            if (snapshot.empty) {
                t.set(docRef, {
                    uid: venueId,
                    reservation: reservation
                });
                return Promise.resolve('Reservation Complete');
            }
            return Promise.reject('Seats already taken');
        })
    });
}).then(result => {
  console.log('Transaction success!');
}).catch(err => {
  console.log('Transaction failure:', err);
});
```

**NOTE**: As you can see on the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_and_array-contains-any) for `array-contains-any`, this where clause will be limited to 10 values on your `reservation.selectedSeats` array. Also I am not sure if you have to use `venueId` to get the empty document or not, since you want to use that ID, so I encourage you to try both ways.

Comment: Thank you! I 've tried it and the transaction success is printed. However, the t.set does not work because there is nothing in the database. Moreover, result is undefined. Any ideas?

Comment: add a `console.log('The snapshot is empty!');` inside the condition to check if the snapshot retrieved is empty or not and let me know if it logs, also can you share how the reservation object is mounted (ie. what fields it has and what is it populated with)?

Comment: yes, the snapshot is empty and works as expected. When the same seat is selected, it goes to seats already taken., the object is like the one i provided in the example. Here's my customised version which works without the t.set https://jsfiddle.net/7ckwhbvu/

Comment: You are trying to use `.doc().set(object)`, which does not work, since `set()` needs to be called like this `.doc(docId).set(object)`, if you want to create a brand new document on that collection you need to do use `add()` instead of `set()`. Try it out and let me know if it works.

Comment: the code above works, the issue is that it won't work using t.set(). When i call add() it creates a new document with a random unique id.

Comment: ah, now I understood what you mean, in that case, using what I mentioned earlier for `set()`, you should actually call the `.doc(id)` before it, so using what you shared on jsfiddle as an example, you could do this: `databaseRef.collection('reservations').doc(beachId).collection('res').doc('someId').set({beachId, uid, date: '29/05/2020', selectedSeats }, {merge: true});`. That way, if the document with id`"someId"` does not exists, it will be created with that id. Does that solve the issue?

Comment: actually the code i on the fiddle works already but it does not utilise the transaction (t.set()). Having said that i am not sure if the transaction will work without the t.set(). I hope you understand what i am saying ;p

Comment: Right, so to the code of the answer itself, what happens if you do a `t.doc(venueId).set({reservation})`? And what about `t.doc(venueId).set(reservation)`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214916/discussion-between-pantelis-and-ralemos).